# how do i add text with union in sql?

Tags: sql

I have two tables: 
Family - with columns: Name, ID 
Money - with columns: ID, salary, expenses 
I have to add each name that his expenses bigger then his salary, the text "spender".
and to all the rest names add the text "frugal".
How to use the Union command to do this?

Comment: can you please exaplian this in brief with example , so  we can help you

Comment: This may vary from RDBMS. What sql engine (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server) are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need a union for this. A join should do:

```
SELECT
   f.Name, 
   CASE WHEN(SUM(m.Expenses) > SUM(m.Salary)) THEN 'Spender' 
        ELSE 'Frugal' END AS SomeClass
   FROM 
      Family f 
      INNER JOIN Money m
      ON f.ID = m.ID
   GROUP BY
      f.Name
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51d58/2)